# How can I make a UIButton have a minimum width and ignore its intrinsicContentSize in iOS / Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit, autolayout

I need to layout a `UIButton` so if the title has a single character, then it ignores its `intrinsicContentSize` and uses a constant width, but if it has a long title, then set its trailing anchor (aka width) to be the `UICollectionViewCell` trailing anchor minus 10 pts to account for some trailing padding.

What Im doing is this.

```
button.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
```

Which works almost as expected but I dont know how to make the button have a minimum size, so as of now if I set a single character to my button, AutoLayout of course uses the intrinsicContentSize and I end up with a tiny button.

Something tells me it has something to do with Content Hugging / Resistance priorities but Ive been playing a bit with those and havent been able to come up with what I expect.

Comment: How about simply a "width >= some constant" constraint?

Comment: Thought about it yeah, but if the API returns me a super long text, how can I limit the max width of the button to the cells trailing anchor minus 10 points to account for some padding?